The first call to rand() gives steadily growing number across the runs, even with srand(time(NULL))
As title, I notice that the output of the first call to rand() seems to be a 9-digit number that steadily increases across the runs. The second call seems normal. Is this something well-known?
This is the code on my Mac
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  srand(time(NULL));

  printf("%d\n", rand());
  printf("%d\n", rand());
  return 0;
}

Here is my Makefile
BINARIES := test

all: $(BINARIES)

clean:
    $(RM) $(BINARIES) *~ *.dSYM

CXXFLAGS := -Wall -g -std=gnu++11 -O3
CXX := g++

RM := rm -r

This is the output of 8 runs
➜  Coding ./test
830930336
360000711
➜  Coding ./test
830963950
924951209
➜  Coding ./test
830980757
1207426458
➜  Coding ./test
831014371
1772376956
➜  Coding ./test
831064792
472319056
➜  Coding ./test
831081599
754794305
➜  Coding ./test
831098406
1037269554
➜  Coding ./test
831115213
1319744803

I tried srand(time(0)) and it does not change anything.

It’s pseudo random numbers

It is well known that rand is pretty crappy. rand seeded with the current time is crappier still. Here's a good presentation on how crappy it can get and the modern alternatives. Plus it's pretty funny.

I tried srand(time(0)) and it does not change anything. Seeding should make a difference. Without seeding at all you should get the same sequence every time. With srand(time(0)) or srand(time(NULL)); (which do the exact same thing) you will have a slightly different seed if you run the program more than 1 second apart.

C++ has high-quality random number generation that is preferable to the awful rand() function that was inherited from C.

rand wasn't awful in the 1970s that spawned it. But now that we have chips that can outperform a Dorito at number-crunching rand, it's pretty weak compared to the alternatives. Amazing how much 50 years can change things.

This varies upon implementation, but the first call to rand() is often the seed itself. It wouldn't surprise me if srand takes the passed in value (timestamp) - divides it in half or something, and that becomes the return value for the next call to rand().  I bet you if you were to print the value of time(NULL) alongside the first call to rand(), you'd see an obvious correlation.

Is this something well-known?  Yes.

In the deep-dark, long-ago days of the 1990s, n00b me was advised to always discard the first value returned by rand because too often the first value was effectively useless when it came to randomness. So, yeah, this has been going on for quite a while.

Thanks to everybody for replying. Shame on me that I didn't know it at all.

The biggest problem here is the seed, not rand. Using std::time(NULL) as a seed is a bad idea. On many systems, the time values it returns have a  one-second resolution. When a fast-running program makes several calls to srand(time(NULL)), there is a significant chance that all of them will use the same seed!

(cont.) If the time values used as seeds are not identical, they may be very similar. In that case, if the PRNG does not condition the seed in some way, to further randomize it, then the initial outputs from the PRNG could be similar. This may be what you are observing. Cycling the generator a "small" number of times can lessen the effect of such a seeding.

(cont.) All your problems will likely go away, if you change the seed to this: std::srand(std::random_device{}()). First, check that your compiler has a good implementation of std::random_device. Modern compilers generally do. Prior to version 9.2, however, MinGW distributions of GCC used std::mt19937 with a fixed seed! On those systems, std::random_device generated the same sequence every time.

Thank you! These are helpful and I shall try them later.

For this Stack Overflow answer, I tested five different implementations of rand that were seeded by srand(time(NULL)). For each test, rand was seeded in two ways: (1) srand(time(NULL)), and (2) srand(random_device{}()). When the engine underlying rand was mt19937 or pcg32, the poor seeds generated by (1) mostly worked. When rand implemented a version MINSTD (as it does in Xcode), seeding with (1) failed. Option (2) worked in all cases.

Thank you very much. Could you clarify what it means to work, to fail, and to work mostly? Are you talking about the randomness, or about the first call to rand() that I mentioned?

By "worked," I mean that—after calling std::srand(std::time(NULL))—the first call to std::rand produced values that appeared, to the naked eye, to be random. When rand was implemented with std::mt19937 and pcg32, the seeding was successful. It worked. When rand was implemented with tbx::knuth_lcg, it "mostly worked." (Which kinda means, "It didn't work!" There were issues.) When rand was implemented with std::minstd_rand0 or std::minstd_rand, it failed. See the post I linked above for a fuller explanation.

Of course, when the calls to srand(time(NULL)) were closely spaced, and the time values used as seeds were identical, none of the seedings "worked." That is what I was referring to above, when I said that std::mt19937 and pcg32 "mostly worked." Otherwise, if the seed values differed by as little as 1 second, those two generators worked.

I see, thanks for clarifying! It's so weird that I learned to code in C++ more than two decades ago and don't remember anything like this :(
